# Copy values from multiple columns through via script - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In this script I can copy **column A** from **row 1 to the last row containing values** and send it to **column H** of another worksheet.

But I can't adjust to copy **column A, B, C and D** and send them at the same time to the other worksheet in **Column H, I, J, K**.

What do I need to do to make it possible to **copy 4 columns** at once without having to use formulas within the spreadsheet?

```
function TestesGerais() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAA');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet13');
  var range = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),1);
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBB');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet14');
  ts.getRange(1,8, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Note: Thanks @Cooper (https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) for alerting me to an error in my script and my question, already details updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function TestesGerais() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAA');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet13');
  var range = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),4);//Simple change made the last one a four.  This is something you should be able to do for yourself.
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBB');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet14');
  ts.getRange(1,8, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```